# How to fix class imbalance in dialogue (text) time series data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, imbalanced-data

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df.head(5)


 data                                                     labels
0  [0.0009808844009380855, 0.0008974465127279559]             1
1  [0.0007158940267629654, 0.0008202958833774329]             3
2  [0.00040971929722210984, 0.000393972522972382]             3
3  [7.916243163372941e-05, 7.401835468434177e243]             3
4  [8.447556379936086e-05, 8.600626393842705e-05]             3
```

The 'data' column is my X and the labels is y. The df has 34890 rows. Each row contains 2 floats. The data represents a bunch of sequential text and each observation is a representation of a sentence. There are 5 classes.

I am training it on this LSTM code:

```
data = df.data.values
labels = pd.get_dummies(df['labels']).values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data,labels, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 42)

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1])) # shape = (31401, 1, 5)
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1])) # shape = (3489, 1, 5)
### y_train shape =  (31401, 5)
### y_test shape =  (3489, 5)

### Bi_LSTM
Bi_LSTM = Sequential()
Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32)))
Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Dropout(.5))
# Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Flatten())
Bi_LSTM.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))

def compile_and_fit(history):

    history.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = history.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              epochs=30,
              batch_size=32,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    return history

LSTM_history = compile_and_fit(Bi_LSTM)
```

The model trains, but the val accuracy is fixed at 53% for every epoch. I am assuming this is because of my class imbalance problem (1 class takes up ~53% of the data, the other 4 are somewhat evenly distributed throughout the remaining 47%).

How do I balance my data? I am aware of typical over/under sampling techniques on non-time series data, but I can't over/under sample because that would  mess with the sequential time-series nature of the data. Any advice?

#### EDIT

I am attempting to use the class_weight argument in Keras to address this. I am passing this dict into the class_weight argument:

```
class_weights = {
    0: 1/len(df[df.label == 1]),
    1: 1/len(df[df.label == 2]),
    2: 1/len(df[df.label == 3]),
    3: 1/len(df[df.label == 4]),
    4: 1/len(df[df.label == 5]),
}
```

Which I am basing off of this recommendation:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342170/how-to-train-an-lstm-when-the-sequence-has-imbalanced-classes

However, the acc/loss is now really awful. I get ~30% accuracy with a dense net, so I expected the LSTM to be an improvement. See acc/loss curves below:

[image]

Comment: Try assigning the weight to class/label. You can try for focal loss also.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on both of your suggestions?

Comment: cell no. 15 and 19 -> https://www.kaggle.com/hirayukis/lightgbm-keras-and-4-kfold

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342170/how-to-train-an-lstm-when-the-sequence-has-imbalanced-classes

Comment: @Pygirl thanks for the link, that was helpful. I have tried to implement this, but the training is very bad. I supplied the code of my implementation. Is this how you would do it?

Comment: you need more features and a better architecture. Also if possible try to use adam instead of rmsprop.

Answer (score 1):

Keras/Tensorflow enable to use `class_weight` or `sample_weights` in `model.fit` method

`class_weight` affects the relative weight of each class in the calculation of the objective function. `sample_weights`, as the name suggests, allows further control of the relative weight of samples that belong to the same class

`class_weight` accepts a dictionary where you compute the weights of each class while `sample_weights` receive a univariate array of dim == len(y_train) where you assign specific weight to each sample